How to configure ServiceProviderOptions with HostApplicationBuilder instead of HostBuilder with .NET Generic Host?
What i'm doing :
In a console application (not related to ASP.NET) I'm using the .NET Generic Host template in .NET 8.
I can force service provider options with UseDefaultServiceProvider extension method on IHostBuilder created with Host.CreateDefaultBuilder() :
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
builder.UseDefaultServiceProvider((ServiceProviderOptions opt) =>
{
    opt.ValidateOnBuild = true;
    opt.ValidateScopes = true;
});

What I want to do :
There's a new method Host.CreateApplicationBuilder() that returns an IHostApplicationBuilder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host?tabs=appbuilder#set-up-a-host).
I would like to use it, but there are no similar extensions methods on this interface and I found no way to access ServiceProviderOptions.

You can call HostApplicationBuilder.ConfigureContainer (a method present on and pass a IServiceProviderFactory which is just a new DefaultServiceProvider(yourOptionsHere).

That's good enough for me (new DefaultServiceProviderFactory(yourOptionsHere)), if you put your comment as an answer i will mark it as a accepted.
